# How to Create & Use Components in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

"when I create File class in Laravel, after type use File; I have error: Cannot use 'File' because the name is already in use"

Answer (score 1):

You have to give it an Alias, for example:

```
use App\Helpers\File as CustomFile;
```

Laravel does that all the time, for example, look for this in your app:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
```